# Nested Form Gem produces broken Blueprint after rails upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, upgrade, nested-forms

I'm upgrading my rails app from 3.0.x to 3.2.x and I'm using the [nested form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) for one of my content forms.

It used to work fine but now the blueprint HTML no longer generates properly and nothing happens when I click the link:

```
<%= f.link_to_add "Add a slide", :slides %>
```

however I get no JS errors in the console.

The working old blueprint used to look like this:

```
<div id="slides_fields_blueprint" style="display: none">
  <div class="fields">
    <MY FORM FIELDS HTML HERE>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, after the upgrade to 3.2, it looks like this:

```
<div data-blueprint="<div class="fields"><MY FORM FIELDS HTML HERE></div>" id="slides_fields_blueprint" style="display: none"></div>
```

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out nested form 0.3.x does things differently than the old 0.2.x series and just doing

```
gem 'nested_form', '0.2.3'
```

solved my problem.  I'm not exactly sure why upgrading the gem caused a problem because their documentation still looks like the same syntax that I'm using but there might be something subtle I missed.